# ImportError: No module named 'UserString' in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

When I run spark using python3 on cluster. This error keeps come up:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 24, us-lax-office-dev-03.vpc.supplyframe.com): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glin/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/home/glin/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/home/glin/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 419, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ImportError: No module named 'UserString'
```

I know that in python3 "UserString" is not a module anymore it is a part of the collections module. But I cannot fix it. Is there anyone who can help????

If I change my master node to local[*] this error will goes away.....I'm so comfused

Comment: Any code comes with that error?

Comment: @LostInOverflow   I'm not sure if this error coming from my code, I was just using spark to parsing and filter some web log data. "/home/glin/" is the place that spark are installed.                                       I though that the error is not coming from my code, because: First, I'm running well on another cluster, Second, I'm running well on local. I'm trying to use this cluster because it has more cores than the good one that I'm using.....

Answer (score 0):

> I know that in python3 "UserString" is not a module anymore it is a part of the collections module. But I cannot fix it.

Why cannot you fix it? Instead of

```
import UserString
```

can you try

```
from collections import UserString
```

Comment: You may revert back to python2 if you cannot access the source code. You should choose an env that gives you more control.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the problem, and what I cannot understand is that I could not find where UserString module was imported.
Then I found python packages in my Yarn cluster had different versions. One was python3.4.5 and the others were python3.4.3. After I reinstalled, the problem was solved.

Additionally, in my case, the direct cause was comparison between str and NoneType.